# The system is experiencing problem that requested for support

Tags: httpwebrequest

HI,

We created a web application which is running in many web servers. One of the server was recently updated. When they request the web page which usually streaming PDF content, the alert message displayed and return back to last page visited.

The alert message has the title: Windows Internet Explorer

Alert message is "The System is experiencing problem that requested for support".

We never faced this exception. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Comment: More Information Required, Please Post Programming Language, Code, Other Relevant Details

Comment: We developed the application using ASP.NET framework and C# language.

IIS 6 is used as web server.

Answer (score 1):

grep your source code for the message; it's probably raised by javascript in your app.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when this problem occurs? Does the browser crash?

I've seen this sometimes with IE. I don't know why. It has happened when dowloading Excel spreadsheets, but it has also happened when downloading code from SourceForge.

Comment: No, the browser is not crashing. It just loads the last visited page.

Comment: Then see the answer from @tpdi below. This does not appear to be a message from .NET or IIS or IE. I bet it's from your code.